# UIView from XIB-file: height is NULL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiview, xib

I have created a custom view with a XIB file and are loading the XIB as a UIView several times into my project fine.

But i want to know the size of the UIView that was created with the XIB File. (Not the best idea i know, but just to make sure i'm using the correct size even if the XIB file is resized later)

My code in the viewDidLoad from my UIViewController:

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
coverArticle *pageView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
[coverArticlesScrollView addSubview:pageView];
NSLog(@"View size: %@",pageView.frame.size.width);
```

The "pageView.frame.size.width" is returning NULL. Why is this ?

Comment: Not sure if printing a CGFloat as a string is supported.  Try `NSLog(@"View Size: %f", pageView.frame.size.width);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSLog(@"View Size: %f", pageView.frame.size.width);` width/height is of CGFloat type